# How can I keep user keep user logged in RingCentral while using Authorization code flow?

Tags: oauth-2.0, ringcentral

In web phone call, I am using Authorization flow. Currently, On page load, I have called URL for an authorization code and after that user will be logged and perform Inbound and Outbound call operations. But when the user opens a new tab, the user need to generate authorization code and login. I am not able to store any credentials in the database as well. so please let me what way I can prevent login process again and again.

Comment: Did the answer I provided for using LocalStorage to store the access_token help? Do you still have more questions or any new information about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing more about how your application code is structured, it is difficult to answer this question properly. It is much easier to answer questions here which have code you've implemented or have tested to solve the problem. If you could provide that, it would help.

In the meantime, could you store `access_token` in LocalStorage? Then if the user opens a new tab, your app can use the existing token in localStorage?